# Run-time error '1004' Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' Failed

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am new to VBA as I have just started learning it.

Right now I'm facing a problem in exporting the message body from outlook to excel. The funny thing is when i run the first time, it works. But when when i run the second time, the error message as stated in my title appears.

I clicked on the debug and it highlighted this code: "offsetRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row"

I have tried various way like selecting the worksheet that I wanted to paste the data into it but to no avail. Therefore, I hope the experts here can assist me in debugging the code. Also feel free to feedback on my coding if I have done any redundancy that will slow my computer.

FYI, this is for my work so that I can export out the email contents into excel. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim strSheet As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim intRowCounter As Integer
Dim intColumnCounter As Integer
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim nms As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim fld As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim itm As Object
Dim masterData() As String
Dim subData() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim offsetRow As Long

strSheet = "For fun.xlsx"
strPath = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\New folder\"
strSheet = strPath & strSheet

Set nms = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fld = nms.PickFolder

'Handle potential errors with Select Folder dialog box.
If fld Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Thank you for using this service.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf fld.DefaultItemType <> olMailItem Then
    MsgBox "Please select the correct folder.", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
ElseIf fld.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no mail messages to export", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Open and activate Excel workbook.
Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open (strSheet)
Set wkb = appExcel.ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")

wks.Activate
appExcel.Application.Visible = True  

'Copy field items in mail folder.
For Each itm In fld.Items
    Set msg = itm
    masterData = Split(msg.Body, vbCrLf) 'Seperate according to lines
    For i = 0 To UBound(masterData)
        If masterData(i) = "" Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            'do the split here
            subData = Split(masterData(i), vbTab)
            wks.Activate
            offsetRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This is where the error appears
            If i = 0 Then
                intRowCounter = i + offsetRow + 1
            Else
                intRowCounter = i + offsetRow
            End If
            For intColumnCounter = 0 To UBound(subData)
                Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter + 1)
                rng.Value = subData(intColumnCounter)
            Next intColumnCounter
        End If
    Next i
Next itm

Set appExcel = Nothing
Set wkb = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set msg = Nothing
Set nms = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set itm = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try this `offsetRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the:

```
offsetRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

into

```
With wks
    offsetRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

and it works now.

Comment: A possibility for optimization is in Chris Neilsen's answer: saves two lines of code doing exactly the same :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is because you don't qualify the Excel range references

Change

```
offsetRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This is where the error appears
```

To

```
offsetRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
```

BTW there are a lot of optimisations that can be done to this code

Comment: @Siddharth - didn't see your comment, I probably was still typing when you posted.  (Good point about the `-4162`)

Comment: No Worries Chris :) + 1 For explaining it :)

Comment: BTW, if OP is doing Early Binding then you can use `xlUp` as well. I wrote `-4162` out of habit :)

Comment: Thanks Chris and siddharth for the help. Anyway 1 hr after posted this question, I have figured it but due to the 7 hrs rule, I can't post my answer. Anyway it is putting a "with" statement.

Then regarding the optimisation of the code, what do you suggest?